# Does anyone know of an embeddable and customizable calendar with a rolling view?

Tags: jquery, html, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to find an embeddable and customizable calendar that has a week rolling view. All the calendars I've looked at (google, upto, etc) have week, month or agenda views, but none seem to have a view which automatically starts on today's date and shows the events for the next 7 days. Bonus points If the calendar can be synced with google calendars.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use 30boxes.com for hosting my web calendars. Then use RSS to insert a feed widget on my webpage. You can edit the feeder to list today's events first and set the number of upcoming events to display. You can also enable a scroll function if desired. I use Feedwind from feed.mikle.com for my RSS feed display. Not the most elegant system, but it does enable me to allow employees to add events through 30 boxes, saving me some work.

Comment: thank you joe. I had actually looked into it before, but I couldn't find any samples for it. would you have a link available to see what you've done?